# Scale independent Canvas

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML `Canvas` that can be scaled (more specifically it is a child of an object that is scaled), and scaling it causes it's output to become aliased.  This is occurring because the `Canvas` uses its size to determine the framebuffer size.

What I actually want to happen is for the framebuffer to track the `Canvas` size multiplied by its scale i.e. its on-screen pixel size.

My initial idea was to set the `canvasWindow` and `canvasSize` to the scaled size, but it seems that there is no decoupling between the `Canvas` 'pixel' size and the framebuffer's because the whole image began to render beyond the bounds of the `Canvas`.

In this example the black ring in rendered inside a `Canvas` that is parented to the scaled grey rectangle:

[image: Before]
[image: After]

```
Canvas {
    id: borderCanvas
    anchors {
        fill: parent
        margins: 4
    }

    antialiasing: true
    canvasWindow: Qt.rect( 0,0,
                           width * parent.scale,
                           height * parent.scale );
    canvasSize: Qt.size( width * parent.scale,
                         height * parent.scale );

    onCanvasWindowChanged: {
        requestPaint();
    }

    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext( "2d" );
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvasWindow.width, canvasWindow.height );

        ctx.strokeStyle = Sy_application_qml.paletteObject.buttonText;
        ctx.lineWidth = 4 * parent.scale;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc( canvasWindow.width / 2,
                 canvasWindow.height / 2,
                 ( canvasWindow.width / 2 ) - ctx.lineWidth,
                 0,
                 Math.PI * 2 );
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

So is there anyway to set the `Canvas` framebuffer size such that scaling transformations do not affect it?

### Edit

If I leave `canvasWindow` at the default, and just update the `canvasSize` then I don't get the framebuffer rendering beyond the `Canvas` bounds - but the output is still at a low resolution so `canvasSize` still isn't actually changing the
size of the framebuffer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to inverse the inherited scale transformation on the `Canvas`, and then increase the height and width by the scale amount.  This leaves the the `Canvas` the same size on the screen but with a framebuffer to match.

```
Canvas {
    id: borderCanvas
    anchors {
        top: parent.top
        left: parent.left
        margins: 4
    }

    property real viewScale: base.parent.scale

    scale: 1.0 / viewScale
    height: ( parent.height - ( anchors.margins * 2 ) ) * viewScale
    width:  ( parent.width  - ( anchors.margins * 2 ) ) * viewScale

    antialiasing: true
    transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft

    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext( "2d" );
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, width, height );

        ctx.strokeStyle = Sy_application_qml.paletteObject.buttonText;
        ctx.lineWidth = 4 * viewScale;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc( width / 2,
                 height / 2,
                 ( width / 2 ) - ctx.lineWidth,
                 0,
                 Math.PI * 2 );
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

[image: Before]
[image: After]